# Android: How do I show 2 notifications in a row

Tags: android, android-notifications

The method bellow is being called twice with a different `name` parameter but only 1 notification appears on my device (the last one). I thought that putting an unique request mode parameter inside `PendingIntent.getActivity()` with `name.hashCode()` would work but that didn't solve the problem. So how can I alter this method to make my device show 2 notifications in a row instead of just the last one?

```
private void showNotification(String name, String sub) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(),
                FragmentTabsPager.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                activity.getApplicationContext(), name.hashCode(), intent, 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                activity.getApplicationContext());  
        builder.setContentTitle("Hello world"
                ).setContentText(name+" from "+sub)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon).setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .getNotification();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) activity
                .getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                        Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = builder.getNotification();      
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;        
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;      
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter to `notify()` is the ID of the notification. That needs to be different if you want different `Notification`s to appear on the screen. If you call `notify()` twice with the same ID, the `Notification` is replaced, not added.